# how to Customize Webbrowser?

Tags: android, browser, web

Creating a webbrowser custom!

I or WE need a custom webbrowser , so far i have a webviewer, or so it seems... i wish that it doesn't start running the current webbrowser on my Phone

so briefly

**I want a custom webbrowser ... 
visit most recent visited pages ...
avoid running google chrome** *or any other Webbrowser app on my phone*

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView ourBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
        ourBrowser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/09/android-webview-example.html check this example

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Zirco](http://code.google.com/p/zirco-browser/) browser. It is open source and based on `Webview`. You can further customize it for your need.